# Read from a file and tokenise input C

Tags: c, arrays, char, fgets, strtok

I'm having trouble with a piece of coding I'm working on. It involves linked lists and certain annoying pointers. Here is some sample code:

```
PersonType *person;
FILE *c;
c = fopen("file.csv", "r");
char in[100];
fgets(in, 80, c); //Edited

root->head->next = 0;
char *getNum = strtok(in, ";");
char *getName = strtok(NULL, ";");
char *getHome = strtok(NULL, ";");
strcpy(root->head->getNum, getNum);
strcpy(root->head->getName, getName);
strcpy(root->head->getHome, getHome);
person = root->head;
if(person != 0){
    while(person->next != 0){
        person=person->next;
    }
}
//DEGUG
printf("Successfully Made a Person NODE");
```

The code won't read from the file and I am completely stumped why. In the XCODE debugger/tracer it initializes all the get chars with nil. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

EXAMPLE FILE

```
P1;Elyza;45 Random RD
P2;Ian;78 Shark CL
```

Comment: always good to check return codes

Comment: Indeed, there is no telling whether the file was successfully opened or not. Verify that c != NULL, then verify that the result of fgets != NULL.

Comment: you say you have problems with pointers and stuff, in that case you  need to show how the structures that you use are declared and allocated otherwise it is impossible to give a straight answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = fopen("file.csv", "r");
char in[100];
fgets(in, 80, cin);
```

you probably meant

```
c = fopen("file.csv", "r");
char in[100];
fgets(in, 80, c);  // <---
```

also make sure you check return value from `fopen()` to handle the case that the file is not found.

Comment: Oops.. Cin IS meant to be 'c' still can't figure it out.. Sorry

Comment: you don't show `root` and `root->head` so it is difficult to help you with that. e.g. do you allocate memory for them?

Answer (score 0):

```
fgets(in, 80, cin);
```

There's your problem.
Surely you meant to read from the `FILE* c`:

```
fgets(in, 80, c);
```

Comment: There's nothing called cin in C. And had it been C++, the compiler would have complained about incorrect types passed to fgets.

Comment: If it compiles, then the compiler is crap and needs to be replaced with a real one. `cin` is of type `std::istream`, not `FILE*`.

Comment: Okay then. I'll be more subtle.